# How to list distinct column after a join and also count?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp-classic, adodb

I have three tables:

```
team(ID, name)
goal(ID, team_ID, goalType_ID, date)
goalType(ID, name)
```

As you can see, team_ID is the ID of teams table, and goalType_ID is the ID of goalType table.

For all teams, I want to list the number of different types of goals that ever happened, 0 should appear if none.

We don't need to care about the goals table since we don't need the name of the type of goal so I've gotten to the follow code that only uses the first two tables:

```
SELECT team.ID, team.name, goal.goaType_ID
FROM team LEFT JOIN goal ON team.ID=goal.team_ID
```

What this results in is a three-column table of information I want, but I would like to count the number of DISTINCT goalTypes, and GROUP BY team.ID or team.name and keep it three columns and also if the result is null, show 0 (team might not have scored any goals).

The resulting table looks something like this:

```
team.ID     team.name   goalsType.ID
1           Team_1      1
2           Team_2      2
2           Team_2      2
2           Team_2      2
3           Team_3      4
4           Team_4      null
5           Team_5      null
6           Team_6      1
6           Team_6      2
6           Team_6      4
6           Team_6      3
7           Team_7      5
7           Team_7      4
8           Team_8      null
```

I have tried a combination of GROUP BY, DISTINCT, and COUNT, but still can't get a result I want.

Am I going about this all wrong?

### Edit

Based on Gordon Linoff's answer, I tried doing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT team.name, COUNT(goal.goalType_ID)
FROM team LEFT JOIN goal ON team.ID=goal.team_ID
GROUP BY team.ID, team.name
```

and it will give me:

```
Name        #0
Team_1      1
Team_2      3
Team_3      1
Team_4      0
Team_5      0
Team_6      4
Team_7      1
Team_8      0
```

If I try to use "DISTINCT team.ID, DISTINCT team.name", it will error out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT team.ID, team.name, count(distinct goal.goalType_ID) as NumGoalTypes
FROM team LEFT JOIN
     goal
     ON team.ID = goal.team_ID
GROUP BY team.ID, team.name;
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. It's also giving me very vague errors as well: "The command contained one or more errors. [,,,,,]"

Comment: @PGT . . . That seems like a strange error for something that is just a modification to the query in your question.

Comment: It's a front end error that gets printed out, I do not have the privilege of seeing the server-side error. It will show that error no matter what kind of error. I'll update the description with a modification of your answer.

Comment: @PGT . . . You should try the query first in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: hmm this really should work but I guess 'count(distinct goal.goalType_ID)' isn't compatible with adodb on iis6 on ms server 2003?

Comment: @PGT . . . I don't know about the interface, but `count(distinct)` has worked at least since SQL Server 2000 (and before, because the code is based on Sybase which also supports `count(distinct)`).  Perhaps there is some confusion somewhere with Access, which does not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ec680/13

```
;WITH cte 
      AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY tname 
                    ORDER BY goalid), * from temp)--temp= Your join statement  
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN a.goalid IS NULL THEN 0 
         ELSE a.row_n 
       END [count], 
       a.tid, 
       a.tname, 
       a.goalid 
FROM   cte a 
       JOIN (SELECT Max(row_n) row_n, 
                    tname 
             FROM   cte 
             GROUP  BY tname) b 
         ON a.row_n = b.row_n 
        AND a.tname = b.tname
```